# Count out the XSLT Average value of Price

Tags: xslt, count, sum, average, price

I'm a little stuck with my XSLT, I'm tyring tofigure out how to count out the average price in XSLT for all my car ads.

So I've got this XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Uppgift3.xsl"?>
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 dörrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klima/automatic, cruise, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 dörrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.fönster/speglar/säten, soltak, c.lås, servo, airbag, startspärr, antispinn, cruise., alu., träinred., sort skinn, mitttarmstöd., sportssäten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. Röd/Silver,tankväska medföljer. 146hk Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb affär. Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 dörrar, 78.000 km. el.fönster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medföljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.fönster/spegel, 8xalu., c.lås, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 dörrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godkänd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullständig service, 1 ägare, 6 högtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/fönster/soltak, fj.c.lås, st.spärr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baksäte, m.armstöd, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 dörrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.fönster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.lås, servo, airbag, rökfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidoväskor, bagagefästen. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.fönster/speil, c.lås, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, röd. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, träint, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. Är som ny, karbon anlägg, nya däck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

As you can see we have all types of cars.
Now they all have a total price. 
What I've done so far is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/autoads">
 <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Bilar</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Antal Äldre än 1999</th>
        <th>Antal Yngre än 1999</th>
        <th>Antal Automat</th>
        <th>Antal Ej Automat</th>
        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar äldre än 19999</th>
        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar ungre än 19999</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']), '0')"/> </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']), '0')"/></td>
           <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(ad[contains(adtext, 'automatic')]), '0')"/>
           </td>
           <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(ad[not(contains(adtext, 'automatic'))]), '0')"/>   
           </td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']/price), '0.00')"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']/price), '0.00')"/></td>
       </tr>


      </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the above does not count out the average price, I've tried to use the whole count of the cars like this

```
   <xsl:variabel name="carsbelow19" select="format-number(count(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']), '0')"/>
   <xsl:variabel name="carsabove19" select="format-number(count(ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']), '0')"/>
```

And then use them as this

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ad[regyear &lt;= '1999'] div $carsbelow19), '0.00')"/></td>
```

But this gives me an error. So I dont think that I can use the whole variabel and link the existing cars as a "div".

Does someone know a solution or can point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Comment: `xsl:variabel` is not a valid XST element name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/autoads">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Bilar</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Antal Äldre än 1999</th>
                        <th>Antal Yngre än 1999</th>
                        <th>Antal Automat</th>
                        <th>Antal Ej Automat</th>
                        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar äldre än 19999</th>
                        <th>Genomsnitts pris för bilar ungre än 19999</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:variable name="carsbelow19" select="ad[regyear &lt;= '1999']"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="carsabove19" select="ad[regyear &gt;= '1999']"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count($carsbelow19)"/> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count($carsabove19)"/> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(ad[contains(adtext, 'automatic')])"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(ad[not(contains(adtext, 'automatic'))])"/>   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($carsbelow19/price) div count($carsbelow19), '0.00')"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($carsabove19/price) div count($carsabove19), '0.00')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**NOTE:** You are including the year 1999 in **both** variables. I believe you need to remove the `=` from one of them.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply and a nice solution! The think is both variabel are suposed to look for 1999, the only difference is the lt & gt, where I want one to look for 1999 and others that are not 1999(I mean above 1999).

Comment: @K.wok If you want to include cars **above** 1999, you need to use `[regyear &gt; '1999']`. The way you have it now, you are counting the cars in 1999 twice (you can see that the totals do not match).